# Sum of the components of a variable - Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have defined a variable which has two elements `y[i,j]`. How can I sum all the components of this variable in Modelica?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very simple:

`sum(y)`

See also [10.3.4 Reduction Functions and Operators](https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch10.html#reduction-functions-and-operators) in the modelica specification.

Note: Your example does not have 2 elements, but i*j. There are 2 dimensions, with i elements in dimension 1 and j elements in dimension 2. See chapter [10.1 Array Declarations](https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch10.html#array-declarations%20for%20details) for details.